# Mariadb/MySQL databases keep failing

Tags: mysql, mariadb

hope you can help.
My Mariadb/MySQL databases keep failing with this message in the log:

```
===============
Service Error
(XID fseu38) The “mysql” service failed to start.
Startup Log
Starting MariaDB.230914 21:53:41 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/gla.glassheadz.com.err'.
230914 21:53:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
.........../etc/init.d/mysql: line 264: kill: (31815) - No such process
 ERROR!
=================
```

Line 64 is part of this code:

```
wait_for_ready () {
  i=0
  while test $i -ne $service_startup_timeout ; do
    if $bindir/mysqladmin ping >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      log_success_msg
      return 0
    elif kill -0 $! ; then
      :  # mysqld_safe is still running
    else
      # mysqld_safe is no longer running, abort the wait loop
      break
    fi
    echo $echo_n ".$echo_c"
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    sleep 1
  done
```

if you try to load a website such as goodinthehead.com, you see `Error establishing database connection`
The problem resolves after a reboot but the error reoccurs after a day or two, so it may or may not work when you try it.

I am not proficient enough to try and decipher the error...

extract from https://glassheadz.com/error.html

```
2023-09-01  2:04:42 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 110M, instances = 1, chunk size = 110M
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner coordinator priority: -20
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './meta01_hemp/wp_commentmeta.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``meta01_hemp`.`wp_commentmeta``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `meta01_hemp`.`wp_commentmeta` because it could not be opened.
....
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.27 started; log sequence number 3938880214; transaction id 64368475
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230901  2:05:13
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2023-09-01  2:05:13 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: The message tells you further details should be in `/var/lib/mysql/gla.glassheadz.com.err`. What does that file contain?

Comment: Thankyou Barmer - I spent ages trying to make it look right for ppl. :)

Comment: @ceejayoz That file is 60Mb so I snipped out a section which is all of the same date, You can see it here at https://glassheadz.com/error.html

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
```

This means another mariadb instance is already running on the same datadir.

The service/init script being used isn't sufficiently protecting the data. Systemd services do a pretty good job.

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './meta01_hemp/wp_commentmeta.ibd' OS error: 71
[ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
[ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
```

This means its expecting an innodb file to exist and it doesn't. Something may have been damaged by dual processes running on the same datadir.

First looks for existing `mysqld` processes and cleanly shut them down.

InnoDB added much stronger protection against multiple versions running in [MDEV-31568](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31568) (10.5.22+).

Comment: Thanks so much for your time to look at this. I'm a lot closer to fixing it now - really appreciate your time :)

Comment: I eventually found an installation of a Forum plugin which had an innodb. Removed all that now (when you delete the plugin it does not remove the database..) and so far no failures and Mariadb restarts successfully when a restart is run.
Thanks everyone! saved me a lot of time and bother. :)

Comment: @user2510689 - I hope you have pointed out the issue to the plugin owner.